# How to Open Form 2 from Form 1 and close Form 1 in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

When I open Order Form from Dashboard Form, Order Form appears, Dashboard Form is hidden. But when I want to close it. Dashboard Form is still running. I need to manually stop it in vb.net. Anyone help!!

```
Public Class frmDashboard
    Private Sub btnDashboard_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDashboard.Click
        Me.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnOrders_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOrders.Click
        frmOrders.Show()
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: This is normal behavior. Why do you expect the first form to close by itself when you open another one?

Comment: Your first sub has `Me.Show()` That makes no sense. You wouldn't be able to see if the button if the Form was not already shown.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you shouldn't do that... but if it's really what you want...

On Form2, add something like that :

`public Parent as Windows.Forms.Form`

On Form1, when you open Form2, set Parent = Form1

```
Private Sub btnOrders_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOrders.Click
    Form2.Parent = Me
    Form2.Show()
End Sub
```

So, on Form2, you can close Form1 when Form2 is closing.

```
 Private Sub Form2_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, _
           ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

    Parent.Close()

End Sub
```

But, as I wrote, I think you shouldn't do that... it's not a common behaviour.
Instead of closing Form1, I suggest you to refresh it / reload / make it visible again (by using the Parent variable)

Comment: Why should you not open one form and close the first form?

Comment: Because that's not a common behaviour and so not what users expect.
Most of the time, a child window don't close the parent window.

You have a dashboard from which you can open orders.
As a user, I expect the dashboard stay opened under the order I've opened, so when I close the order I can open another order from the dashboard. Or close the dashboard if I no longer need it.
When closing the order window, I expect it ask to the dashboard window to refresh itself, so it reflect my work on the order.

Comment: That is your pattern. Other applications have different patterns. There is basically nothing wrong with closing opening a form and then closing the calling form.

Comment: I agree. When writing installers or updaters, people expect the form to close after the new form is launched.  It's extremely common with forms like "there's an update available? would you like to install?" [yes] [no]